# How to goto a nxt / ardor wallet with a default address set in the url?

Tags: nxt, ardor

Is there a way to open up the nxt / ardor wallet in the browser and immediately go open up the account you want to view? How would you put it in the url parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ardor you also need to specify the chain i.e. https://ardor.jelurida.com/index.html?account=NXT-YD9C-ZKZW-ZZLZ-BNB3W&chain=IGNIS